# stage scaling and aligning in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage

I would like to do in AS3 inside a package to align left and forbid stage scaling.

Here is my code:

```
[SWF(width="640", height="480", frameRate="31", backgroundColor="0x000000")]    

public class Main extends Sprite
{
```

This code works but I would like to not to use the first line and prefer to do something like this:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

But this fails to compile.

I would like to dynamically set the stage width and height.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot change your SWF's width and height dynamically. This is done when compiling.

You can adjust `stageWidth` and `stageHeight`, but they will only affect the appearance of your graphics when you change the `scaleMode` and the `align` properties.